# UITableViewCell shifts the content when reloaded

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am using a **custom UITableViewCell** with a **UILabel** at the top ,a **UIButton** just below the label and **another UILabel**,just under this button.

Final UILabel will be hidden initially,and will be opened when button action is called.The height of all the label and the cell are dynamic.

But

> When i select the button ,the cell shifts its contentview to the.
>   center

I need the content of the cells to start at the origin itself.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ReferenceCell";
    ReferenceiPadTableCell *cell = (ReferenceiPadTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReferenceiPadTableCell" owner:self options:Nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
    }
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    NSDictionary *referenceDictionary = [self.referencesList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *nameString = [referenceDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];


    CGSize labelSize = [nameString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]
                              constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(listTableView.frame.size.width - 15, 125)
                                  lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    labelSize.height =  labelSize.height > 96? labelSize.height : 96;

    cell.l1.text = nameString;
    cell.l1.frame = CGRectMake(cell.l1.frame.origin.x, 6, cell.l1.frame.size.width, labelSize.height);

    cell.button.tag = [[referenceDictionary objectForKey:@"sort"] intValue];
    [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(showList:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.l2.hidden = YES;


    cell.button.frame = CGRectMake(cell.button.frame.origin.x, cell.l1.frame.origin.y+ labelSize.height + 1, cell.l1.frame.size.width, cell.l1.frame.size.height);

    if ([self.showList objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"showList-%d", indexPath.row]] )
    {
        cell.l2.hidden = NO;
        NSDictionary *dic = [self.abstractList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        NSString *abtString = [dic objectForKey:@"name"];
        CGSize absSize = [abtString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]
                               constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(tableView.frame.size.width - 15, 125)
                                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        cell.l2.frame = CGRectMake(cell.button.frame.origin.x, cell.button.frame.origin.y+ cell.button.frame.size.height + 3, cell.button.frame.size.width, absSize.height);
        cell.l2.text = abtString;
    }

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Can you post code which you have done so far ...

Comment: please share your complete cell code, so that we can really help you!

Comment: Please show us some code. Hardly to tell what's wrong only from description.

Comment: post your code and screenshot..

Comment: put code of  cellForRowAtIndexPath method ...

Comment: While assigning frame instead of using cell.l1.frame.origin.x use 0, if you want to start your label from starting of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

it's doesn't shift the content but added more subview on UITableViewCell because you are not using reusing cell concept well.So use concept like this

```
  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
   {
UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]     initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];

UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]init];
lbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
lbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
UIImageView *imgView1=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
UIImageView *imgView2=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
UIImageView *imgView3=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
 UIImageView *imgView4=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
      lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:20];
}
else
{
      lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:30];
}
[cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];

[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];

[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView1];

[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView2];

[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView3];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView4];
return  cell;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell=[self tableView:tableView reuseTableViewCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier withIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

    }
 }
}
```